# python indentation, SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

Please what's wrong with my python code, it always reports File "lake.py", line 28 SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I wonder, is it the brackets? or what could be causing the error, I will appreciate any help thank you

```
def count(m, n):
    if(n < m):
        temp = n
        n = m
        m = temp

    return m * (m + 1) * (2 * m + 1) / 6 + (n - m) * m * (m + 1) / 2


arr = []
arr2 = []

foo = 100
n = foo
if (n == 1):
    print('1')
    print('1 1')
else:
    for m in range(n):
        n=(((6 * foo) - (m * (m + 1) * (2 * m + 1))) / (3 * ((m * m) + m))) + m

        if (count(m, n) == foo and m <= n):
            arr.append(''+str(int(m))+' ' + str(int(n))+'')
            if(m != n):
                arr2.append(''+str(int(n)+' ' + str(int(m)+'')


    arr = arr + arr2
    arrLength = len(arr)
    print(arrLength)

    for g in range(arrLength):
        print(arr[g])
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a line 34 in the posted code.

Comment: `arr2.append(''+str(int(n)+' ' + str(int(m)+'')` has five left parentheses, and three right parentheses.

Comment: sorry it was File "lake.py", line 28 , will update the code

Comment: None of this code is at all Pythonic. You don't need a temp variable to swap, and you shouldn't iterate over a range.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have parenthesis out of place.

`arr2.append(''+str(int(n)+' ' + str(int(m)+'')`

should be

`arr2.append(''+str(int(n))+' ' + str(int(m))+'')`

Comment: In total yes but really no  !
it should change to
`arr2.append(''+str(int(n)) +' ' + str(int(m))+'')`


because `arr2.append(''+str(int(n)+' ' + str(int(m)+'')))` will get **TypeError** 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 0):

In line `25` change `'arr2.append(''+str(int(n)+' ' + str(int(m)+'')'` to `arr2.append(''+str(int(n)) +' ' + str(int(m))+'')`

**Note** : after i runned your code i see a error

```
 n=(((6 * foo) - (m * (m + 1) * (2 * m + 1))) / (3 * ((m * m) + m))) + m

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

That's because you use `foo =100` (in line 13) and then use `n = foo` So after `for m in range(n):` the loop will started with `0`

so m is zero now ! and in

```
n=(((6 * foo) - (m * (m + 1) * (2 * m + 1))) / (3 * ((m * m) + m))) + m
```

your program will throw an exception

So for Fixing this part you can change `for m in range(n):` to

```
 for m in range(1 ,n):
```